# How to set a state to refresh a google-map-content automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built a small boat visualizer. I am using [AISHub APIs](https://www.aishub.net/api). After fetching data from the APIs I am able to obtain a `json` file with the vessels I am interested in and inject these vessels inside a table.
The user has to manually update the page pushing the refresh button on top left of the page to see the new updated table.

[image: map]

**The problem**: How to set a state to refresh the `google-map` content automatically every minute instead of the user doing it manually?

Below the code:

**GoogleMap.js**

```
class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: true,
            buttonClickedAt: null,
            progress: 0,
            ships: [],
            type: 'All',
            shipTypes: [],
            activeShipTypes: [],
            logoMap: {}
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
        this.countDownInterval = null;
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (!this.state.buttonClickedAt) return;
            const date = new Date();
            const diff = Math.floor((date.getTime() - this.state.buttonClickedAt.getTime()) / 1000);

            if (diff < 90) {
                this.setState({
                    progress: diff,
                    buttonEnabled: false
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    progress: 0,
                    buttonClickedAt: null,
                    buttonEnabled: true
                });
            }
        }, 500);
        await this.updateRequest();

        const shipTypeResults = await Client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'competitors'
        });

        console.log(shipTypeResults);
        const shipTypes = shipTypeResults.items.map((data) => data.fields);

        const logoMap = shipTypes.reduce((acc, type) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [type.name]: type.images.fields.file.url
            };
        }, {});
        console.log({ shipTypes });
        this.setState({
            logoMap
        });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.type !== prevState.type) {
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.countdownInterval);
    }

    async updateRequest() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/hello';
        console.log(url);
        const fetchingData = await fetch(url);
        const ships = await fetchingData.json();

        console.log(ships);

        this.setState({
            buttonEnabled: false,
            buttonClickedAt: new Date(),
            progress: 0,
            ships
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ buttonEnabled: true });
        });
    }


render() {
    return (
        <div className="google-map">
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'KEY' }}
                center={{
                    lat: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.latitude : 42.4,
                    lng: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.longitude : -71.1
                }}
                zoom={8}
            >
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

A good way would be using a `setTimeout()` but would that be correct? Where should that be applied and how?

```
setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload();
    }, 60 * 1000);
```

Or maybe setting an interval as a refresh rate?

I am a bit confused on what would the best way to approach this.

Comment: timeout run just once, use setInterval, store the return from the interval in some var and block the interval before unmount (so the interval doesn't continue after you change page). Not sure if this is the best solution though

Comment: @EulerRibeiroSudbrack, thanks for taking the time to read the question. Could you please provide an answer with some code if that is possible?  That would make me understand your suggestion.

Comment: I've posted an answer (not tested so maybe you have to make some tweaks :])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your request function i guess u want to disable the button while the api doesn't return, so maybe move this piece above the requests:

```
    this.setState({
        buttonEnabled: false,
        buttonClickedAt: new Date(),
        progress: 0,
        ships
    });
```

If im wrong you could remove the timeout from the second setState and call as a callback on the first like this:

```
    this.setState({
        buttonEnabled: false,
        buttonClickedAt: new Date(),
        progress: 0,
        ships
    }, () => {
        this.setState({ buttonEnabled: true });
    });
```

on the last part instead of location.reload() set a interval calling the update on ur componentDidMount:

```
let updateInterval = setInterval(() => { 
  this.updateRequest();
}, 60 * 1000);
this.setState({updateInterval})
```

then on the componentWillUnmount you clear the interval `this.state.updateInterval`